# Add a sharing contact with GDK

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I was looking at the Google Glass GDK, and was looking if you could add a sharing contact from your appliction. I didn't see any references to that in the official documents, and I was wondering if you could do this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: associated google-code issue https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=267

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current sneak peek of the GDK does not support adding share contacts yet. If you are interested in this feature, please file a feature request in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list)!