# Creating sharing option using GDK

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm using the GDK, and I'm trying to create an app to share things to. For example, after setting up the Twitter application for Glass, the user has an option to share a photo directly to Twitter. How can I create a similar option for a service using the GDK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a sharing contact with GDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205734/add-a-sharing-contact-with-gdk)