# Share content from Immersion on Google Glass?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-glass

Is there a way to share text or image content from a native Glassware Immersion (not using Mirror API)? We would ideally like to share content to Google+ or Twitter, but haven't found a way.

I tried firing an ACTION_SEND Intent, but it says no apps are available to handle it.

Is this possible with the GDK? Latest version at time of writing was XE11.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a sharing contact with GDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205734/add-a-sharing-contact-with-gdk)

Answer (score 2):

A few of us have already sent a "Share" GDK request [here: http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=230](http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=230)

The issue been accepted so far just waiting for release.